# asp.net DataGrid Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have the following asp.net DataGrid:

```
    <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="AutoGenerateTable" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" OnEditCommand="AutoGenerateTable_Edit" OnCancelCommand="btn_CancelEdits" OnUpdateCommand="btn_Update">
        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" />
        <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Bold="true" />

        <Columns>
             <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Country" DataField="Country" ReadOnly="True"/>
             <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Partner" DataField="Partner" ReadOnly="True"/>
             <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Product" DataField="Product" ReadOnly="True"/>
            <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Flag">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal id="FlagText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Flag")%>'/> 
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="FlagFropDown" >
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Auto Fulfill" Value="1" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Do Not Auto Fulfill" Value="0" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
            <asp:EditCommandColumn HeaderText="Edit" EditText="Edit" CancelText="Cancel" UpdateText="Update" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

Which all works fine except for one thing.

When I edit the data, I use a DropDownList to provide the options for the user.

I want set the value of the dropdown when the user presses 'edit'.

The problem is I cannot find the control, as it does not exist when the edit button is pressed, and so I get an "Object not set to instance" error

Once the button has been pressed and the dropdown is on the screen, I can find the control when calling the update method, so I know it does get there eventually.

But how can I set it at the point when the user presses 'Edit'.

I have tried finding the control from the page and calling the method with a delay, but this does not work.

eg:

```
....
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        setIndexDropdown();
    }
    public void setIndexDropdown()
    {
        DropDownList DropDown = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("FlagFropDown");
        Response.Write(DropDown.ID);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Any ideas??

EDIT

Code for edit function:

```
public void AutoGenerateTable_Edit(Object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    AutoGenerateTable.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
    List<string> flag = new List<string>();
        flag.Add("Auto Fulfill");
        flag.Add("Do Not Auto Fulfill");
    AutoGenerateTable.DataSource = populateTable();
    AutoGenerateTable.DataBind();
    Literal text = e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[1] as Literal;

DropDownList list = e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[1] as DropDownList;
}
```

Comment: On which event you are coding?

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin OnEditCommand

Comment: Can we please see the code of your `EditCommand` event?

Comment: @j.f. I have posted the code

Comment: whats the error in updated code?

Comment: Thanks. Where are you trying to find the DropDownList? I don't see it in that event.

Comment: @j.f. I have added in the code that will find the dropdownlist once it is visible, but this will not work on the update method as that control does not exist

Comment: Oh, so it works when you click the edit button, but not the update button?

Comment: @j.f. other way around, when I click the edit button it does not work as it does not exist, but when I click the update button it does exist so it works

Comment: Oh ok, I see your problem. I'll write up an answer. Give me a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `DataGridItem` you are trying to find your control in. `e`, your variable for your `DataGridCommandEventArgs`, are the arguments for the command *before* the edit. So the `DataGridItem` contains all of the controls **not** in edit mode. Meaning your DropDownList will not exist.

What you need to do is get the `DataGridItem` of that row *after* the bind. The `DataGridItem` would then contain all of the controls that **are** in edit mode. You already have the row index, so just get the new `DataGridItem` using that.

```
public void AutoGenerateTable_Edit(Object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Put the data grid into edit mode
    AutoGenerateTable.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
    List<string> flag = new List<string>();
        flag.Add("Auto Fulfill");
        flag.Add("Do Not Auto Fulfill");
    AutoGenerateTable.DataSource = populateTable();
    AutoGenerateTable.DataBind();
    Literal text = e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[1] as Literal;

    // Get the row again now that we are in edit mode
    DataGridItem editItem = AutoGenerateTable.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex];
    DropDownList FlagFropDown = (DropDownList)editItem.FindControl("FlagFropDown");

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I know we should not say thank you on here, but that was really bugging me so thank you I really appreciate your help

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! I will never stop someone from being polite.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code. Hope It will helpful for you

```
  protected void AutoGenerateTable_EditCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            // / Set the EditItemIndex property to the index of the item clicked 
            // in the DataGrid control to enable editing for that item. Be sure
            // to rebind the DateGrid to the data source to refresh the control.
            AutoGenerateTable.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
            BindGrid();
        }


    protected void AutoGenerateTable_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Literal FlagText = null;
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            FlagText = e.Item.FindControl("FlagText") as Literal;
        }
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem)
        {
            DropDownList FlagFropDown = e.Item.FindControl("FlagFropDown") as DropDownList;
            if (FlagText != null)
            {
                string value = FlagText.Text.Trim();
                if (FlagFropDown != null)
                {
                    //now you have got the object of dropdown
                    //If you want to do any opertaion on dropdown can write code for it.
                    FlagFropDown.Items.FindByText(value).Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```